# EXTJS 3.4 items alignment issues in panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Team I am facing two issues with item alignment in ext js panel. I am using extjs version 3.4.

Basically I want to align panel text boxes horizontally two in each line but as of now only one is coming per row.

also it seems there is no space coming between panel and first text box. Is there any way we can do this in EXTJS 3.4

code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World Window</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


    Ext.onReady(function(){
        var tab2 = new Ext.FormPanel({
            labelAlign: 'left',
            labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;',
            labelWidth: 85,
            title: 'formname',
            bodyStyle:'padding:5px',
            scrollable:'true',
            border:'true',
            width: 1200,
            height:600,
            items: [{
                xtype:'panel',
                height:200,
                autoScroll:true,            
                defaults: {flex: 1, layout: 'form', border: false},
                layout:'hbox',
                items:[{
                title:'Personal Details',
                defaultType: 'textfield',   
                    items: [

                        {   
                            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                            name: 'first',
                            width:200,
                            allowBlank:false,
                            value: 'Jack'
                        },{
                            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                            name: 'last',
                            width:200,
                            value: 'Slocum'

                        },{ 
                            xtype:'combo',
                            fieldLabel: 'Company',
                            name: 'company',
                            width:200,
                            value: 'Ext JS'
                        }, {
                            fieldLabel: 'Email',
                            name: 'email',
                            width:200,
                            vtype:'email'
                        }]

                }]
                }],
            buttons: [{
            text: 'Save'
            },{
            text: 'Cancel'
            }]
        });

    tab2.render(document.body); 


});
</script> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO easiest way is to use `FormLayout` and modify positioning by CSS. Each field in `FormLayout` is wrapped in `div.x-form-item`, so you can set `float: left` style for it. If width of fields is adjusted to the width of panel this is all you need to do. Othwerwise you will have to set `clear: left` on every seconond field.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wC5hZ/2/

You can also use `TableLayout` but it would be more code.